# Restore locally installed fonts after LibreOffice upgrade

Tags: updates, libreoffice, fonts

This morning I got the LibreOffice upgrade from 5.4.3 to 5.4.4 (Version: 5.4.4.2; Build ID: 1:5.4.4-0ubuntu5, to be precise).

With this upgrade, a number of fonts I had **locally** installed on my (standard Ubuntu) system have disappeared from the Writer font dialog. This includes:

- my SIL fonts, including Andika New Basic, Charis SIL, and Gentium Plus
- all the ClearType (Cambria, Calibri, etc.) fonts
- PT family
- SBL Greek and SBL Hebrew
- ... and more.

Just to make it really weird, *some* persist: e.g. IA Writer Duospace, Merriweather [serif and sans], Venturis ADF, one or two others. These are all installed in the same way and from the same location as those listed above as missing in LibO.

Now, this behaviour [seems to have been noticed](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115441) on the LibreOffice bug tracker, and it's pretty bad behaviour, I reckon. (IF that's what I'm experiencing.) And that's their problem, and not quite what I'm seeking help with here.

My question for AskUbuntu is this: these fonts are still in `~/.local/share/fonts`, so I simply ran `sudo fc-cache -f -v` expecting them all to re-appear in my LibO install.

But they haven't shown up. I re-ran the `fc-cache` command, logged-out, logged-in, ... still not showing up.

How can this be? Here's an example of the problem (with a font that other applications find and use without any trouble):

[image: screenshot]

The salient details of that image as text are:

1. The LibreOffice Writer "Character" dialog for "Andika New Basic" giving the message: `This font has not been installed. The closest available font will be used.`
2. But the terminal output for `fc-list | grep -i Andika` shows that this font **is** installed.

I'm not even sure I'm understanding where the problem lies. But I would VERY much like LibO Writer to use the fonts I have installed on my system, many of which are my day-to-day workhorse fonts. I confess to being somewhat grumpy.

---

**Update** (2018-03-05) - I got the update to Version: 6.0.1.1 today, and this problem has disappeared. The suggestion on the [LibO bug tracker](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115723) is that there was a packaging issue with 5.4.4*, but whether that is correct, it's not a concern in v. 6.0+.

Comment: This is a bug that happens [on windows as well](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97982)

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: For any others affected: the bug report now has [confirmation from another user](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115723#c4) in the same situation (on Ubuntu 17.10) -- so, it's not "just me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I filed a [bug report with LibreOffice](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115723), some things came clear: describing the problem really does help!

After much head-scratching, it dawned on me that the problem ONLY affects locally-installed (per-user) TTF fonts, but it does **not** affect locally installed OTF fonts, **nor** does it affect TTF fonts installed system-wide.

The **work-around**, then, is to move any `~/.local/share/fonts/*.TTF` files to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`, then run `sudo fc-cache -f -v`.

At least this means that the fonts are available to LibO Writer (and Calc, etc.), although it still seems like a bug to me.

Comment: According to the bug report that you linked this appears to be resolved or at least isn't reproducible with the [latest version](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/)

Comment: My apologies for any confusion you may have experienced. By latest version I meant the latest version of  LibreOffice, not to be confused with the latest version in the repositories.