# How to Reload Fonts in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

As per [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/17323/adding-fonts-to-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-1304beta/#17324) answer on installing fonts into LibreOffice (LO), I have several fonts downloaded into my `/usr/share/fonts` folder that were recognized by LO. However, after an general update, LO no longer has those fonts loaded.

Is there a quick (e.g., command line) way to reload all fonts into LO that are stored in the `/usr/share/fonts` folder and its sub-folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LibreOffice needs no other "loading" than the system itself provides. Make sure you run `sudo fc-cache -f -v` from the terminal to update fonts for the system. That should be all LibO needs to find them. See further help on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts).

If the fonts are stored locally (i.e., ~/.local/share/fonts), you might have run into [the TTF problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005777/), but that was specific to the LibO 5.4.4x version(s), and is no longer an issue for 6.0+.

Comment: I also needed to restart my machine after running `sudo fc-cache -f -v`, but it worked. Thank you, [@Dɑvïd](https://askubuntu.com/users/38585)!

Comment: I have LO v.6.0.7 in Xubuntu 18.04 and installed `ttf-bitstream-vera` from apt, then ran `sudo fc-cache -fv` and rebooted, without effect. The font files are indeed installed in `/usr/share/font/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/`. What can be wrong here...?

Comment: Ok, got it (duh): I confused "Bitstream Vera" with "Bitstream Charter"... Because the latter does not appear through an apt search. Just learned that it disappeared between Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, because it's an Adobe font...

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic?

I *removed* the non-Latin fonts from /usr/share/fonts/truetype and ran fc-cache -fv.

Imagine my horror when LibreOffice still listed the removed fonts, so I added option -r (really-force) to erase, then rebuild the cache:

```
sudo fc-cache -frv
```